# Android Studio showing "unable to start daemon process"

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, jdk1.8-73

I am unable to use my android studio after i change my jdk directory in the project structure menu I  receive a message saying " unable to start daemon process"  [image: unable to start daemon process]